RAMP function block Value Reached always true
I'm using TC3 Ramp function block FB_CTRL_RAMP_GENERATOR.  The function block configure as below
stCTRL_RAMP_GENERATOR_PARAMS.tTaskCycleTime := T#10s;
stCTRL_RAMP_GENERATOR_PARAMS.tCtrlCycleTime := T#10s;
stCTRL_RAMP_GENERATOR_PARAMS.fVeloPos:= (fTargetTemp-fInitTemp)/(60.0*fRampTime); (* in units per second *)
stCTRL_RAMP_GENERATOR_PARAMS.fVeloNeg:= 0; (* in units per second *)



    bCTRL_RAMP_GENERATOR(bEnable    := True,
                                fStart  := fInitTemp,
                                fTarget := fTargetTemp,
                    stParams:= stCTRL_RAMP_GENERATOR_PARAMS,
                                fOut    => fRampOut,
                                bValueReached=> bValueReached,
                                bError  => bError,
                                eErrorId    => eErrorId);

The fStart set to 25 degree and the target set to 30 degree.  When I start the program, the bValueReached become true although the target value not reached yet.  What's going wrong?  Is it VeloPos and VeloNeg configure wrong?

Don't have a twincat installation here, so I cannot try this. But try this: Instead of setting bEnable to True, give it a rising edge when you want the function to start.

how to say rising edge, the true I just hard code for here.  In my actual program, it get from the start button.  When user press start, it will enable

Okay, I hope to be able to try it tonight, but another thing which looks weird: tCtrlCyleTime should be equal to your cycle time. 10 seconds sounds really high for that.
After that, you could also set your taskCycleTime lower (probably 0.5 or 1 second)

I have try set to 1 seconds but also the same.

fRampTime I set to 2 or 10 also same return, bValueReached is true.

For accurate timing with this function block, tTaskCycleTime must be set to match the cycle time of the calling task (by default T#10ms in TC3). tCtrlCycleTime can be something larger than this if you don't want the ramp to calculate every cycle.
You are probably seeing bValueReached come on almost immediately because tTaskCycleTime is set way too high and is causing the ramp to progress much faster than it should.

T#10s for both tTaskCycleTime and tCtrlCycleTime  is it ok?  The task cycle time I didn't modify, it remain 10s.  the fRampTime i set to 2.

No, as I said you need to use T#10ms (unless you have modified the task time of your TC3 program from its default value). That's milliseconds, not seconds.
